# Homogenization of Dirichlet problem.

Tags: periodic-functions

I am studying asymptotic analysis of periodic medium. Epsi is the periodic parameter. aij are considered regular. Here I have $$a_{ij} ^\epsilon (x) = a_{ij} (\frac{x} {\epsilon}) $$
And it says that this function would has derivative of order $\frac{1} {\epsilon} $.
I think its like $x^3 $ has derivative of order three.
But if I consider $\frac{x} {4} $ it's seems wrong.

Also when we talk about x belongs bounded subset of $R^n *] 0,T[$
 This model turns into 
$$ a_{ij} ^\epsilon (x, t) = a_ij ( x, \frac{x} {\epsilon} , t, \frac{t} {\epsilon^k)$$

And then says it not have bounded derivative with respect to t. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKVLW.jpg)
I want a clear idea so I can move further with clear concepts.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please edit your post to make it more clear? In particular the equations are hard for me to follow. See some tips on [how to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [**LaTeX / MathJax**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). You may also take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already.

Comment: Please answer I m waiting...